# MDC button ripple does not draw at all

Tags: javascript, mdc-components, ripple-effect

So I am using MDC (Material design components) without node.js, meaning I have to import it like this:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```

So the CSS works fine, I can use any class from the MDC and it works flawlessly.

But there is some partial problem with the JavaScript additional effects. The TextField works fine - when I click it, the text shifts. But any other JS effect is not working.

```
<label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
          <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
          <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
            <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="my-label-id">OpenWeatherMap API key</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="my-label-id" style="width: 512px;">
      </label>
      <br>
        <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
            <span class="mdc-button__label">Grant location permision</span>
          </button>
    <script>
            mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-button')); <!-- This does not work>
            mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field')); <!-- This works fine>
        </script>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I tried everything I found.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `mdc-button__ripple` element inside button:

```html
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
  <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span>
  <span class="mdc-button__label">Grant location permision</span>
</button>
```